# Cannot install Ubuntu on an Acer Aspire One 756

Tags: installation, dual-boot, acer, aspire-one

I have used Ubuntu before, in virtual machines, but today I decided to make the leap and I bought a netbook to install Ubuntu as a "real" OS alongside Windows. The netbook I bought is an Acer Aspire One 756, with a 64-bit Intel processor, 4GB RAM, and Windows 8 as the default OS.

I have now encountered several obstacles that actually prevent me from installing Ubuntu 12.10. Here are all the things I have tried so far:

1. **Used a live CD, in combination with a USB DVD drive.** (I should point out that the Aspire One does not have an optical drive.) The computer does not boot in Ubuntu; the drive keeps spinning, but nothing happens, even though I changed the boot order in the BIOS.
2. **Used a USB drive created via the tool available on pendrivelinux.com.** Again, I've made changes to the BIOS to make sure the computer tries to boot from USB before using the built-in HDD. The results vary in this case: sometimes, the computer keeps rebooting like crazy until I remove the USB drive, at which point the computer boots into Windows 8, as expected. If I use a different USB drive, I get an error message that says that the USB drive has been blocked due to "the current security policy".
3. **Tried to install Ubuntu via Wubi.** The program appears to install something, but at some point during the installation process, I get a non-specified error message and nothing else happens.

I am not sure if these are known issues; in any case, searching the forum has not yielded any results, so I thought I should simply describe my problem here in the hope that this question has not been answered before. I would greatly appreciate any help with this annoying problem. Of course, if anything is unclear, do not hesitate to ask for further details.

Comment: WUBI does not work with Windows 8. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-windows-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The current security policy" is probably something to do with UEFI SecureBoot.

See:
[Shimming your way to linux on Windows 8 PCs](http://www.zdnet.com/shimming-your-way-to-linux-on-windows-8-pcs-7000008246/)

There should be a way of switching this off in your BIOS.

The user guide for your machine available here [Acer User Guide](http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=4284) suggests that "Boot Mode" in the BIOS should be "Legacy" for a non windows 8 OS

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the boot mode in BIOS did the trick. I can now boot via USB and run Ubuntu this way.

Of course, this leads to yet another problem: since I now boot in legacy mode, I cannot easily boot back into Windows 8. I need to change the settings in the BIOS again. That is a minor annoyance rather than a real problem, but as a result of that, if I now run the Ubuntu installer, I am not given the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Instead, under the Something else option, I am shown multiple partitions (5 in total) and I do not know which one to choose.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue time ago: I wrote a guide to install ubuntu together with WIN 8

see my answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/328236/181025